# Including a PHP file from a different website on the same managed hosting computer?

Tags: php, server-side-includes

So the old shared web hosting company I used to use allowed me to include a PHP file from one website in my collection in the file of another.

For example:

/home/mywebsite/public_html/functions/functions_xml.php

… could be included in in:

/home/myotherwebsite/public_html/index.php

Now that I am with GoDaddy managed hosting, this doesn't seem to be possible. I've been unable to reach support with Covid19 going on so I'm wondering if there's a PHP setting I can set that will allow files from the same computer but different websites? This worked for shared hosting but apparently not managed. I could use allow_url_include but that just sounds like a bad idea.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have a look at [open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir). Since you don't tell us anything about your system I can't give you further details.

Comment: Make a copy of it for now and call support in two-three months?

Comment: Andreas: I have managed hosting so I managed to get them the next day. They're just not very available at night.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy Managed Hosting had to turn off some protection flag that kept different websites on the same computer from affecting one another.